# Custom extensions files readable & writable only with the program

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography

as you can see the title explains a little.
I know several questions have alreay been asked about custom extensions, but i want also the file i'm using to be readable only from the program i'm writing, and if opened from the explorer,it would not be making any sense(maybe crypted).

The program i'm coding is a substitution cipher
in C++, and it works with two maps, so that every letter in the message would be found in one map, and substituted with the corresponding letter in the other.

I'm trying to store these 2 maps in a file, so how would you suggest i could acheive this ?

P.S: I couldn't find any similar question, If you do, please give me a link

Comment: Hi @AgentChaos. The English in your question is a bit hard to understand. You mention "custom extensions" do you mean "custom Windows explorer extensions"? What are you trying to prevent occurring? You don't want your maps to be readable without a decryption password/key? I'm also uncertain why you're using a substitution cipher. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: -Yes extensions like "txt","exe","mp3" .../     
-Since the file will be alongside the executable, i am trying to prevent the user from reading it/     
-Something like that, the decryption key will be in the source code i guess/     
-No it's just an idea that came into my mind.